# How to check and get the result if the table contain user id in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have create a relationship between user and table column, I want show the table list which is belongs to particular user. For example if user_id 1 is logged in the system, the system will only show the information belong to him which is Table 1.

[image]

This is my controller code :

```
public function show(Request $request){
    $user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $table= Roundtable::findOrFail($user_id);

    return view('users.tables.show')->withTables($table);
}
```

I know that `$table= Roundtable::findOrFail($user_id);` is incorrect but I had no idea how to do because I am new for laravel.

Answer (score 0):

If user has just one table and if `Roundtable` model has `user_id` you can use this query:

```
Roundtable::where('user_id', $id)->first();
```

It will give you user's table or `null` if table doesn't exist.

Another way to get table is to use relation:

```
auth()->user()->roundTable;
```

Comment: It return null value, but when i check from tinker with " App\Roundtable::find(1)->user ", it return the correct user information, so it mean the relationship is exist right? But not sure why it return null.

Comment: This means you've defined `belongsTo()` relation in `Roundtable` model. Now you have to also define [`hasOne()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relation in `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the solution, just need to change the code into

```
$id=Auth::user()->id;
    $table= Roundtable::where('user_id',$id)->get();
    return view('users.tables.show')->withTables($table);
```

then the result will return correctly.